# R Studio stops responding after 2-3 hours of use

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio, tidyr, data-cleaning

Cleaning data in R Studio mainly using tidyr functions and it freezes after 2-3 hours of use. The only way to regain functionality is to close and restart. I've tried stopping the run in console but it remains frozen.

Any thoughts? Using version 2022.12.0 on a PC.

Comment: Very hard to guess what's causing the crash. One easy first recommendation would be to do a fresh install with the newest version and see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to monitor your memory usage and run rm on bigger objects.
Also gc() can help.